# How can I transpose rows to column with SPLIT?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have one STRING column with this name "CampaignName" and with this format inside: "PRODUCT_PHASE_OBJECTIVE_BRAND_(21/01 - 31/01)".

I would like to transpose each part of all rows to columns.

With this structure:

1. Product
2. Phase
3. Objective
4. Brand
5. Date

If I only extract one part, Product, I can run this query

```html
SELECT
  cs.Date,
  c.ExternalCustomerId,
  c.CampaignName,
  SPLIT(c.CampaignName, '_')[OFFSET(0)] part1,
  SUM(cs.Impressions) AS Impressions,
  SUM(cs.Interactions) AS Interactions,
  (SUM(cs.Cost) / 1000000) AS Cost
FROM
  `XXX-266809.zzz.Campaign_3867357697` c
LEFT JOIN
  `XXX-266809.zzz.CampaignBasicStats_3867357697` cs
ON
  (c.CampaignId = cs.CampaignId
   AND cs._DATA_DATE BETWEEN
   DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -365 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))
WHERE
  c._DATA_DATE = c._LATEST_DATE
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4
ORDER BY
  cs. Date DESC
```

But if I try transpose to two columns, my query fails...

```html
SELECT
  cs.Date,
  c.ExternalCustomerId,
  c.CampaignName,
  SPLIT(c.CampaignName, '_')[OFFSET(0)] part1,
  SPLIT(c.CampaignName, '_')[OFFSET(1)] part12,
  SUM(cs.Impressions) AS Impressions,
  SUM(cs.Interactions) AS Interactions,
  (SUM(cs.Cost) / 1000000) AS Cost
FROM
  `XXX-266809.zzz.Campaign_3867357697` c
LEFT JOIN
  `XXX-266809.zzz.CampaignBasicStats_3867357697` cs
ON
  (c.CampaignId = cs.CampaignId
   AND cs._DATA_DATE BETWEEN
   DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -365 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))
WHERE
  c._DATA_DATE = c._LATEST_DATE
GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3, 4
ORDER BY
  cs. Date DESC
```

How can I create a good structure and transpose the data in "CampaignName"?

Thanks!